# How ";" path parameter is validated by tomcat and how struts allows me to enter the class file?

Tags: tomcat, struts, struts-1

I have the following url "/doSomeAction.do" which is mapped to some internal jsp say "/jsp/printNames.jsp"

The following url's

1. /doSomeAction.do and
2. /;/doSomeAction.do does the same operation how?

How struts considers both the request and performs action mapping?

PS: I am using struts1.0